# Logo size on SplashScreen for different resolutions?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

please tell me.

I have slash screen. How to correctly display a logo on it? The logo is centered and indented by 20% the left and right. 
My question is: how big(width) should be the logo for the hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer you to use vector and give it height and width in percents

Comment: I think that this is the best solution, i should read as an android is working with vector images.

Answer (score 0):

Just give static width and height in dp, it will work well

Answer (score 0):

Logo size depends upon your requirements but in general you could refer here for splash screen size guidance https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Splash-Screen-Sizes